# Accessing Array of NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I have declared a NSMutable Array with 50 size. As i want to use each index as an array and add data separately. e.g i want to add 10 object to first Index 5 to next and so on.
Is this the right way to do it?  Please help me out if there is an alternate way.The sdk gives me error at line 5 saying 'Cannot convert to a pointer type'.

```
NSMutableArray *myArray[50];    
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myArray;            
@dynamic myArray; 
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)     
{                                   
    myArray[i] = [NSMutableArray alloc];         
}

PresentationSlides[i] addObject:string];
```

My problem is how can i reach to a specific index.if i use this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)     
{                                   
myArray = [NSMutableArray array];    
}         
[myArray objectAtIndex:i ??????
```

What else?
I am stuck in the projet after completing 90% of it. And there is no use of it if i couldnt complete it.

Comment: I think you are confusing C arrays for Objective-C NSArrays.

Comment: @BoltClock i am sure you have understand what i am trying to do. So can u suggest me a better way. Any optimized solution

Comment: @T. A.: Are you trying to have a C array of 50 NSMutableArrays or an NSMutableArray of 50 objects or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to allocate myArray:

```
myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:50];
```

Then for line 5, in the loop, 'alloc' alone isn't enough. Try:

```
[myArray insertObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10] atIndex:i];
```

Comment: Thats terrific , Now can u tell me , how to access )
0th index of myArray. As the 0th index is itself an array so how can i then traverse in that 0th index.
while(1)
{
[myArray objectAtindex:i++];
}
This code will move the index of myArray i want to move at the indexes of 0th array which are 10.

Comment: `[[myArray objectAtIndex: 0] objectAtIndex: 42];`